# Pipelines in Python? - Think async.js / Haskell's `do` / F#'s `|>`

Tags: python, pipeline, continuations, async.js, delimited-continuations

How can [Continuation-passing style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style) be facilitated from Python?

(I think that's the right term)

---

My code is starting to get messy, I have `map`, `filter` and chains of `lambda`s like so:

```
(lambda a,b: (lambda c:(lambda d: d*d)(c-b))(a*b))(5,6)
```

---

"Pipeline expressions" are found in a variety of languages, for example:

### [F#](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F_Sharp_%28programming_language%29) solution (e.g.: [`|>`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Higher_Order_Functions#The_.7C.3E_Operator))

```f#
let complexFunction =
    2                            (* 2 *)
    |> ( fun x -> x + 5)         (* 2 + 5 = 7 *)
    |> ( fun x -> x * x)         (* 7 * 7 = 49 *)
    |> ( fun x -> x.ToString() ) (* 49.ToString = "49" *)
```

### [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_%28programming_language%29) solution (e.g.: [`do`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation), [pipes](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-4.0.0/docs/Pipes-Tutorial.html))

```haskell
 main = do
     hSetBuffering stdout NoBuffering
     str <- runEffect $
         ("End of input!" <$ P.stdinLn) >-> ("Broken pipe!" <$ P.stdoutLn)
     hPutStrLn stderr str
```

### [JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) (e.g.: [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)):

```js
async.waterfall([
    function(callback) {
        callback(null, 'one', 'two');
    },
    function(arg1, arg2, callback) {
      // arg1 now equals 'one' and arg2 now equals 'two'
        callback(null, 'three');
    },
    function(arg1, callback) {
        // arg1 now equals 'three'
        callback(null, 'done');
    }
], function (err, result) {
    // result now equals 'done'    
});
```

However I understand that this last strategy is more for asynchronous function response resolution (see: [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com)).

#### How do I present all stages of my processing in a single Python expression/line?

Comment: There is a module [Pipe](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe). But for asynchronous execution you will need something like [Twisted](https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/).

Comment: @myaut: Async.js was just an example, maybe I'll replace it with F# and Haskell examples to be clearer.

Comment: @AT Doing your Python example won't gain much readability, as the definition of the second lambda cannot be moved out of the definition of the outermost lambda because it depends on `b`.

Comment: Couldn't you problem being solved by implementing simple [_fluent interface_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface)?

Comment: i would say - don't try to write haskell in python, it's not going to be nice, if you state the problem you're trying to solve i'm sure someone will able to help you

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no standard feature in Python to do that.

There is module called [Pipe](https://github.com/JulienPalard/Pipe) which overrides operator `|`, but it is reasonable considered harmful (overriding operator while changing its semantics).

However, you may implement simple [Fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) for that. Here is an example:

```
class P:
    def __init__(self, initial):
        self.result = initial

    def __call__(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
        self.result = func(self.result, *args, **kwargs)
        return self

    def map(self, func):
        self.result = map(func, self.result)
        return self

    def filter(self, func):
        self.result = filter(func, self.result)
        return self

    def get(self):
        return self.result

x = P(2)(lambda x: x + 5)(lambda x: x * x)(lambda x: str(x)).get()
z = P(range(10)).map(lambda x: x * 3).filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0).get()
print(x, list(z))       # prints 49 [0, 6, 12, 18, 24]
```